# IPersistFile Save() returns 0x80004001 E_NOTIMPL error when saving PDF documents

Tags: delphi, pdf, adobe, ole, ipersistfile

I'm using Delphi 2007. I'm getting 'Not implemented' exception when trying to call `IPersistFile.Save()` after loading document into Ole container. 
Problem exists for Acrobat Reader 10 and higher. The same code works for Acrobat Reader 9.

I was trying to find some solution on Adobe forum but without success. Maybe someone has the same problem before.

I'm using code like this:

```
procedure LoadAndSave();
var PF: IPersistFile;
    saveResult : integer;
    OleContainerDocument: TOleContainer;
    CreateInfo: TCreateInfo;
begin
  CreateInfo := ...
  OleContainerDocument.CreateObjectFromInfo(CreateInfo);

  OleContainerDocument.OleObjectInterface.QueryInterface(IPersistFile, PF);

  if PF <> nil then begin
    saveResult := PF.Save(StringToOleStr(FullFilePath), false);
    //In this place saveResult contains E_NOTIMPL error
  end
end;
```

Comment: The error is pretty self explanatory. The OLE object that is implementing the `IPersistFile` interface does not implement saving a file. What is hard to understand about that? Not surprising for Acrobat, which has a history of restricting features like saving files.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I understand, but I'm looking for some solution for this. How I can save document to not use IPersistFile.Save() method? I can check result code and then call some other method, but which one?

Comment: hard to answer that without seeing how you are accessing the document in the first place.

Comment: In other words: could you make a simple [MCVE] displaying the problem?

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I never had any problems saving files with Acrobat Reader, no matter which version. So it is a little surprising that it doesn't allow saving using the interface. Could it be the .pdf that doesn't allow it?

Comment: @RudyVelthuis if that were the case, I would expect a different error than `E_NOTIMPL`.

Comment: @Remy: yes, that is probably right. I still find it weird that it is not possible through IPersistent.

Comment: There are many IPersist* interfaces... an ActiveX container is supposed to try all of them.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I added some sample code. If you think that is necessary to paste whole working implementation please let me know what you need more to be able to help. Thanks

Comment: @Emil my guess is the object's `IPersistFile` only allows loading but not saving. You might need to ask Adobe about this. On a side note, your code has a memory leak. The pointer returned from `StringToOleStr()` must be freed manually using `SysFreeString()`. Otherwise, use `PWideChar(WideString(FullFilePath))` instead.